# Check what changes retailer made to Windows 11

Tags: windows-10, oem

I'm setting up a couple of new laptops for various purposes. They came with preinstalled Windows 11 Home retail version, not yet setup. After setting it up, I noticed that the retailer (**not** manufacturer) changed the wallpaper, installed browsers and set their default pages to their own.

Short of resetting the Win11 installation, how can I make sure the retailer didn't install any unwanted software? (Here I don't mean bloatware but rather any changes from stock Windows 11 Home)

This is the first time I met with this practice. Is it common?

Additional information:

The seal on the laptop box was broken and was taped over with normal tape, on all laptops. This isn't some small retailer, it's the biggest or second biggest hardware retailer in my country. No, I can't return the laptops.

Comment: Where is this wallpaper?  In UEFI?  Just forget it. In Windows 11? Just change it. Otherwise retailers do not change Windows 11. Not to the best of my knowledge. If they did, they would have orphan machines to support. Large vendors may have their own drivers. Very common over many years.

Comment: *In realistic scenario:* You can't. *In theoretical scenario:* You could install fresh Win11 on the same hardware and semi-manually compare everything - list of installed applications, versions of drivers, registry differences, files on disk. But that's pretty much pointless considering amount of work required.

Comment: "Short of resetting the Win11 installation, how can I make sure the retailer didn't install any unwanted software?" - You can't; Thankfully, there is a feature, that handles your worries (on Windows 11 it's Rest PC on Windows 10 it's Fresh Start). Likewise, [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/give-your-pc-a-fresh-start-0ef73740-b927-549b-b7c9-e6f2b48d275e#ID0EBD=Windows_11) explains if there isn't an `Restore preinstalled apps?` option that means no preinstalled applications were installed.

Comment: @John I will check it the next time I get chance and report back  to you. Very good question. I'm suspecting Win11 since after reinstalling one of the systems cleaned everything.

Comment: @Ramhound I don't think the retailer has a deal with MS, it's most likely something they're doing themselves. Which makes me wonder if it's even legal. I'll check if there is such an option.

Comment: @Aramil Good idea, though it's way too time consuming, even if you write a script for it.

Comment: @m_highlanderish - Doesn’t matter, although I would argue no OEM would survive, if they didn’t play by Microsoft OEM rules. It also doesn’t matter, my suggestion, would still be applicable

Comment: "No, I can't return the laptops." why not?

Answer (score 1):

For installed products, you could compare the date in which Windows
was installed with the dates on which products were installed.

Windows installation date : Found in the Creation date of the folder
`C:\Windows`, as found by right-click on on and selecting Properties.

Product installation date : Found in
*Control Panel > Programs and Features*.
Click on the "Installed On" column to sort it by descending order.